# SharePoint modelling

Tags: 2007

What is the easiest way to model "complex" relationships between SharePoint objects (Websites, Lists, etc)?

I want to store a simple company hierarchy within sharepoint. There are People, Teams, Groups,... and I want to linking People to Teams, Teams to Groups, People to Groups and so on. Each entity should get a nice "Information" Page.

Our old solution was a simple .html website that had hyperlinks to its members and vice versa. What would be the easiest way to acheive this in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question that comes to mind for me is if everything is security trimmed or not, ie: do people only see on the navigation list what they have access to? That adds another level of complexity to it. If you don't care about security trimming you can just use a DVWP to generate a list of lists, and group the necessary information accordingly (obviously not quite as simple as I made it sound, but you get the general idea).

If you're security trimming then there is a bit more involved with it... some custom code deployed via a feature could generate a security trimmed list based on current user; or something along those lines.

Also, if you're simply "modeling" to document/present your structure, take a look at the SharePoint version of [Mindjet](http://mindjet.com/products/mindmanager-for-sharepoint/overview).